# Running a command line not working in browser

Tags: php, cmd, exec, wamp

i'm running WAMP.

When I do:

```
1. run cmd
2. cd c:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.5\
3. press enter
4. php c:\wamp\www\cmdtest\index.php
5. press enter
```

I got the expected output.

But when I do it in the browser, i accessed localhost/cmdtest/exec.php with code:

```
<?php
    exec('php c:\wamp\www\cmdtest\sample.php', $output);
    var_dump($output);
?>
```

The output is empty.

I already set the user of wampapache in services.msc and restart wamp, nothing was fixed...

Any idea why or anyone knows a fix? Thanks in advanced!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried escaping the backslashes?

```
<?php
    chdir('c:\\wamp\\bin\\php\\php5.3.5\\');
    exec('php c:\\wamp\\www\\cmdtest\\sample.php', $output);
    var_dump($output);
?>
```

See also: http://www.tuxradar.com/practicalphp/2/6/2

Comment: thanks for your response @Terry, yes i've tried that but the output is the same.. empty..

Comment: Doh! I was hoping that was the problem :(

Comment: Do you need the cd c:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.5\?

(Could try adding a php chdir('c:\\wamp\\bin\\php\\php5.3.5\\'); before running the exec() : http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.chdir.php)